# Output Attribute

Tags: javascript, html, attributes, output, max

I'm trying to create a basic form that calculates values, in which the max output value is 10. I'm pretty sure it can be done (and odds are, easily so) I'm just not experienced enough to come up with a solution. And searching several forums for output attributes and max value hasn't shed too much light on the matter so far.

So, this is what I have:

```
<form oninput="c.value = parseInt(a.value) + parseInt(b.value)">
<input name="a" type="number"> +
<input name="b" type="number"> =
<output name="c" max="10"></output>
</form>
```

And I don't understand why I can't use max="10" as an attribute, or what else I should do to make it work.

Comment: It looks like you're using HTML forms; if that's the case, A) you should tag it, and B) there's no such thing as an output tag in HTML; you need to read some tutorials on how to use Javascript to get data from a form and then update elements.  If this is not HTML, you should indicate what markup this is

Comment: Thanks for the info. If HTML doesn't use output tags, then it must be javascript, I guess. But I didn't define it on the page (and it still works), so I'm not sure what it is  and I don't want to tag stuff wrong. Obviously, I don't know much about coding, but the lines I came up with get the job done, so I still posted my solution. But, thanks for your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Okay guys. It's a few hours later and I solved it. As I said, I'm pretty sure there is a more obvious and far easier solution, and this one comes with a tiny inaccuracy I don't really care about. So, if you don't like that, write your own code.

```
<form oninput="c.value = parseInt(x.value) - (Math.sqrt((x.value-(10)))||0)*(Math.sqrt((x.value-(10)))||0)">

<input  name="a" type="number"> 
<input  name="b" type="number">
<name="c"></output>
</form>
```

NB: Value x in this example is the result of whatever formula you use "a" and "b" for. (I'm using this one to explain what I did, but if you want to see it in action, then there is a working one at the bottom of this page. Inserting something for x would have looked too messy IMHO). So, once you have a working formula, highlight pareIn(x.value) and the two x.value functions and insert your formula (the one which is using the a and b variables) instead.

If you want your max value bigger than 10, change the number to whatever you want.

And the rest is basic maths.

I'm leaving this here just in case somebody has the same problem and doesn't find a better reference.

And this is the one I put on my page:

```
<form oninput="c.value = (parseInt(a.value)+ parseInt(b.value)) - (Math.sqrt(((parseInt(a.value)+ parseInt(b.value)-(10))))||0)*(Math.sqrt((parseInt(a.value)+ parseInt(b.value)-(10)))||0)">

<input  name="a" type="number"> +
<input  name="b" type="number"> +
<output name="c"></output>
</form>
```

Happy coding.

PS: max="10" doesn't work because apparently it's only an input attribute.